# Convolution of rectangular pulse with sinusoid

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

I have the following convolution

$$ 3 \mbox{rect} \left(\frac{t}{10}\right) \circledast \frac{1}{2}[ \delta(t - 20) + \delta(t+20)] $$

How can I compute it?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo starting point is having to calculate the spectra for 30sinc(10t)*cos(40πt). I calculated the corresponding transforms and ended up with this convolution. Been stuck here

Comment: So, the convolution is in the frequency domain.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo It is. My bad for leaving it out

Comment: What is the difficulty that you're facing? Convolving a rectangular pulse with a Dirac delta is the easiest thing in the world — a mere shift.

Comment: \begin{align}
\texttt{Convolve[UnitStep[\[Tau] + 5] - UnitStep[\[Tau] - 5], 
 1/2 (DiracDelta[\[Tau] - 20] + DiracDelta[\[Tau] + 20]), \[Tau], t]} = \frac{1}{2} (-\theta (t-25)+\theta (t-15)-\theta (t+15)+\theta (t+25)).
\end{align}

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo so the result would be just a sum between two rects shifted at two different values?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is the case.

Comment: Lost myself on something really really easy apparently, thanks!